# Trigger updating all rows

Tags: mysql

I’m having problems with a MySQL TRIGGER.

I have an employees table with some basic information. Then I have a VIEW that we call our finance_system. The finance_system VIEW holds a lot of information from many sources. A few columns in the finance_system are related to an internal sales draw and return random values from other tables each time the finance_system VIEW is queried. Lastly, I have a table called EP1. Its job is to hold some of the data from the finance_system, particularly some of the columns with random values. This keeps them from UPDATING /Changing with every query. The EP1 table gets updated via a TRIGGER that fires AFTER AN UPDATE to certain columns within the employees table. The trigger works and the EP1 table gets updated, but it’s updating the entire table rather than the rows associated to the employee_id that was updated.

I read Stacks policy prior to posting and understand a reproducible example is necessary so I created a Fiddle, but I’ve obfuscated the data and only included a few columns. Hopefully it’s enough as I’ve exhausted Google trying to figure out why it’s not working.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=942dbabba180df86b7ac9317bbcdd64b

Edit:

Simpler version: When Table1.status is updated, the trigger should update Table3.rand1 with the values from Table2.rand1 where the ID’s match. Each ID has two rows in Table2 and Table3. My current problem is that when the trigger fires it updates all the rows in Table3 and I want it to only update the rows associated to the ID that was update in Table1. A join won’t work in this scenario, as Table2 is actually a VIEW using rand() in my real data.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=329e2dd3bf2fff39afc5388721c53ddc

Aimee

Comment: can i see your code ???

Comment: @bigtheo, the code in the Fiddle didn’t help?

Comment: Could you boil this problem down to a basic example (e.g. in your case, the finance_system VIEW is irrelevant) where the trigger does not work as you expect?  Try experimenting with a simple table, a trigger and its desired update mechanism, and post all of that SQL code to the fiddle, so you can get help.

Comment: @Liviu, thanks. I’ve updated the post with a simpler version and new fiddle.

Comment: A) the trigger syntax is wrong, I'm getting errors with both MariaDB and MySQL 8.0.

B) The trigger UPDATE does not seem to have a WHERE clause.  Of course it will update all rows of Table3 unless you put one.  Could you try adding one, perhaps `WHERE Table3.id = NEW.id`?

Comment: @Liviu, Thanks for the help. I fixed the syntax error and tried your where clause suggestion. It gets closer, but you’ll see in the new fiddle it still won’t update by id, and one id seems to override the others. Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5c98ecf9c392a3f81cbbd0889957bfe

Comment: You have 2 mistakes remaining:  the WHERE clause in the subquery is bad, since it points to Table3 instead of Table2.  Then, you are still missing a WHERE clause in the outer query, which I already urged you to fix above.

Comment: @LiviuChircu. I really appreciate all the help! After making your changes I just needed to add a session comparison in the where clause of the sub query and it worked perfectly. Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cd83d25cc3016ee5e3680b54bed490d

Comment: summed up an answer, so the question can be marked as "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the trigger's UPDATE query: it is missing a `WHERE` clause, hence all rows of `Table3` get updated instead of the ones matching the desired `id`.